# Authentication Flow for PIN react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement a screen when the application is minimized and reopened if the time for the application being minimized is more than 2 minutes then a PIN screen should show up instantly.

The logic for showing the PIN Screen when required is working fine. The issue is if I had opened dashboard and minimized it and then reopened the application it opens dashboard and then the screen navigates to PIN Screen.

There is a transition phase where you can clearly see the dashboard for a second or less which I want to avoid.

Any advice how I should handle this?

Because looking at the documentation for react native it is clearly using a loader. I just want to know if there were other ways except this one.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the brief transition phase where the dashboard is showing before the PIN screen, you can apply one of the following strategies:

1. **Splash Screen:** You can implement a splash screen that appears when the app is reopened and then fades out smoothly into the PIN screen. This way, users won't see the dashboard briefly. Splash screens are common in many apps and provide a smoother transition experience.
2. **Background Processing:** Depending on your app's nature, you might be able to do some background processing to prepare the PIN screen before the app is brought to the foreground again. This way, when the user switches back to the app, the PIN screen is already ready to be displayed.